# Pegar caminho de diretorio

Tags: c#

Eu quero pegar um diretorio do sistema, abrir uma janela e nessa janela eu seleciono um diretorio. Consigo selecionar arquivos com o `OpenFileDialog` mas diretorios não.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode utilizar a classe [`FolderBrowserDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
// Instancia a classe.
using (FolderBrowserDialog dirDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog())
{
    // Mostra a janela de escolha do directorio
    DialogResult res = dirDialog.ShowDialog();
    if (res == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // Como o utilizador carregou no OK, o directorio escolhido pode ser acedido da seguinte forma:
        string directorio = dirDialog.SelectedPath;
    }
    else
    {
        // Caso o utilizador tenha cancelado
        // ...
    }
}
```

Alem do uso básico pode ainda permitir ao utilizador criar diretórios pela janela. Para isso coloque a seguinte propriedade a `true`:

```
dirDialog.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
```

Pode ainda decidir qual o directorio escolhido quando a janela e aberta. Para isso utilize a propriedade `FolderBrowserDialog.RootFolder`.

Answer (score 1):

No lugar de usar **OpenFileDialog** use o controle **folderBrowserDialog**

Fonte

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984305%28v=vs.71%29.aspx